# 'diceres vocem eius audiri posse' in 'Fabulae Syrae' in the story of Arachne (pag. 83), what is the correct translation of diceres?

Tags: conjunctive, imperfectum, fabulae-syrae

In 'Fabulae Syrae' capitulum xxxii, in the second story 'Arachne' (pag. 83) while depicting the tapestry that Arachne wove, including the scene of Europa being carried off by Juppiter, this line appears: 'diceres vocem eius audiri posse' My question is regarding the word 'diceres' which is clearly the imperfect subjunctive 2nd person singular, yet how should this be translated? You were saying?

Comment: Can you post more of the context? Having especially the sentence before or afterwards would be helpful. Not everyone has access to the book.

Comment: @cmw Not much context to add I think since it's basically a standalone statement however here is the full preceding sentence:
Arachne vero primum imaginibus illustrat quomodo Europa apud maris litus tauro erepta sit: verus taurus, verae maris undae esse videbantur.
Europa ipsa e dorso tauri in mari natantis terras spectans relictas atque suas amicas, quae in litore manserant, invocans et ab iis auxilium petens cemitur: **diceres vocem eius audiri posse**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use is the so-called potential subjunctive. The relevant sections of Gildersleeve and Lodge, *Latin grammar*, are 257ff.

> 258. The Potential of the Past is the Imperfect Subjunctive, chiefly in the Ideal Second Person, an imaginary "you."
>
> **Crēderēs victōs**, L., II.43,9; *you would, might, have thought them beaten.* **Haud facile discernerēs utrum Hannibal imperātōrī an exercituī cārior esset**, L., XXI.4,3; *not readily could you have decided whether Hannibal was dearer to general or to army.* ...

(In Allen and Greenough's grammar, the relevant sections are 445ff.)

So your passage means "You would have said her [Europa's, presumably] voice could be heard.

Incidentally, this sort of statement is completely typical in a passage of this sort that offers an extended description of some physical object (*ecphrasis*): 'You'd think the figures were actually moving'; 'You'd have said the fire was really burning'; etc.

Comment: Thanks for the citations!